# Dictionary of Lists to CSV in Python

Tags: python, csv

I currently have a dictionary who values are lists.

Example: `{1: [12, 13, 14, 15], 2: [12, 13, 14, 15], 3: [12, 13, 14, 15]}` and so on.

I have 20000 keys, and each list contains 80 values.

I am trying to output this into a CSV file, but have had no luck using Dictwriter.  Here is part of my code:

```
for i in range(0, 3):

    filetxt = "\\Level_3\\" + nonsbar[i]
    filedata = list(csv.reader(open(filetxt,'rb'), delimiter='\t'));

    for j in range (1, len(filedata)):
        tempid = filedata[j][0]
        idind = tempid.index('|')
        geneid = tempid[idind+1:len(tempid)]
        genecount = filedata[j][1]
        nconn[geneid].append(genecount)


for keys in nconn.keys():
    nconn[keys] = zip(nconn[keys])

print "convert to table"
nkeys = nconn.keys()
filetxt = open('nonsmoke.csv', 'wb')
nonsmoketab = csv.DictWriter(filetxt, nkeys,delimiter=',')
nonsmoketab.writeheader()
nonsmoketab.writerow(nconn)
```

I get an ouput like this:

```
114787  114786  
[('161.00',), ('985.00',), ('68.00',)]  [('9.00',), ('19.00',), ('2.00',)]
```

I instead want this:

```
114787 114786   
161     9
985     19
68      2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you want to transpose your dictionary of lists? You can do it with `itertools.izip_longest` for example:

```
from itertools import izip_longest
d = {1: [12, 13, 14, 15], 2: [16, 17, 18], 3: [19, 20, 21, 22]}
labels = d.keys()
rows = izip_longest(*d.values())
```

You can use `csv.writer` to serialize back to csv:

```
import StringIO
buf = StringIO.StringIO()
outf = csv.writer(buf)
outf.writerow(labels)
outf.writerows(rows)
print buf.getvalue()
# 1,2,3
# 12,16,19
# 13,17,20
# 14,18,21
# 15,,22
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked perfectly. Out of curiosity is there a more efficient way of handling all this data, I want to use python for some bayes-net, but I have to discretize the data first.

Comment: @user3131429 you should start a separate thread for a separate question, and describe it in full detail. At least this is free :) and welcomed as long as you're [ontopic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Standard disclaimer, if you found answer useful and serving your needs, cosider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Answer (score 0):

I can give you a rough advise: implement from csv.DictWriter, overwrite method `writerow(self, rowdict)` and `writerows(self, rowdicts)`, add loop on the result from `self._dict_to_list(rowdict)`(it's list in your case) in these 2 functions.